# How to wordwrap mysql data?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Whenever I try to wrap a mysql string with php like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $message = $row['message'];
    $wrappedmessage = wordwrap($message, 3, "\n", true);
    ...
}
```

It never wraps. It adds a space. Say for example the message is "Hello how are you."
it would print "Hel lo how ar e yo u." Whats wrong?

ANSWER:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $id=$row['id'];
  $message = $row['message'];
  $wrappedmessage = wordwrap($message, 3, "<br/>", true);

  echo "$wrappedmessage<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am betting you are viewing the text through a webbrowser.

You'll need to use `<br/>` instead of `\n` as a line break or surround your text with `<pre></pre>` blocks.

EDIT:

Another alternative as suggested by Christian Sciberras in his comment is to use:

```
nl2br(wordwrap($message, 3, "\n", true));
```

Comment: +1 - I bet you are right. :) By the way, with regards to `<br/>` you might want to suggest `nl2br()`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_wordwrap.asp

You should include a `<br />` in the function call alongside `\n`, so it formats the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the PHP_EOL constant instead of "\n". It will generate the newline character for the system PHP is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Is your output going to a browser?  If so, you need to put "`<br />\n`".  Otherwise if your output is at command line the "\n" is enough.